# AngularFire change email doesn't update auth

Tags: angularfire, firebasesimplelogin

I am using AngulariFire with SimpleLogin and I have used the API in order to change the email of a user.

```
simpleLogin.changeEmail(pass, newEmail, profile.email)   .then(function() {
      profile.email = newEmail;
      profile.$save();
      success('Email changed');
    })
```

It works, it change the email on firebase but when i call `simpleLogin.getUser()` i still get the old email, it's like the session or cache has not been updated.
I would not like to logout the user, is there a way to achieve that?

Comment: Did you solve this somehow? I'm facing the same problem.

Comment: I think here you can finde the solution to your problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34108170/changing-firebase-email-doesnt-update-providerdata