# Changing Firebase email doesn't update providerData

Tags: ios, firebase

I'm using Firebase in my iOS app. The user logs in using Firebase's email and password authentication. Currently, I'm creating functionality that lets the user change their email and password.

I noticed that after successfully changing the e-mail address using `changingEmailForUser`, the e-mail address in `authData.providerData` isn't updated. To update it, the user has to log out and log in again (using the new email address).

Is this expected behavior? Can I update the email in the providerData dictionary manually (or is that a bad idea?) or is it possible to force a refresh of the providerData for the logged in user?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is indeed expected behavior. The existing session is "bound" to the old email address. To get a session for the new email address, the user will have to sign in again.

Comment: Thanks. I just authenticated the user again, using the new e-mail address, (while being logged in) and that seems to have solved the problem.